# Skype doesn't always notify about new chat messages

Tags: windows-7, skype, notifications, instant-messaging, chat

So we are both online and sending each other messages in skype from time to time.  I get notifications, answer, and some time later I switch to the Skype window and there are new message about which I wasn't notified. And then the notification starts working again and then sometimes later it skips notifications again, so chat notifications are not really reliable.

Anyone else experiences this? How can I fix this? It's very annoying when the other party writes something and I don't answer, because Skype doesn't tell me there are new messages.

Windows 7 + latest skype, notifications are enabled and usually work, but not always and that's what bothers me.